# SharePoint Workflow 2013 Confusion

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, workflow

I have been creating tasks for users on SharePoint 2010 workflow. But recently I tried creating the tasks in a 2013 Workflow. Though I have noticed that both have different approval process for users. Also 2013 has 2 types of tasks action available.

This is how users approve tasks in 2010:

[image]

But this is not the same case in 2013 Workflow. In that case Users can approve, then again reject, then again set status to 'Pending'. Why so? Why there's a difference between both. We need to do looping, so we will have to use 2013 Workflow, but at the same time how can we achieve the same 'Approval Process' as 2010 Workflow within 2013 Workflows?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, the `Approval Process` at SharePoint 2010 workflow is no longer exist in SharePoint Designer 2013 with SharePoint 2013 workflow platform,

**Why there's a difference between both ?**

This is due to the Workflow form changed from InfoPath form to ASPX form, For more details check SharePoint Designer section at [SharePoint Server 2013 known issues](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SharePoint-Server-2013-known-issues-780242a6-236e-4d7a-8379-118a1aaa2a51?CorrelationId=f7b0b3a3-f817-49d6-bb02-6457b71f5e98&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US&ocmsassetID=HA102919021#__sharepoint_designer_1)

**How can we achieve the same 'Approval Process' as 2010 Workflow within 2013 Workflows?**

I have one suggestion to do that, by combining the SharePoint 2010 workflow with SharePoint 2013 workflow as the following:

- Try to Create A SharePoint 2010 approval workflow that contains the content approval task form .
- At your SharePoint 2013 workflow, Instead of creating `Start Task Process` at SharePoint 2013 Workflow action ,try to add an action that is `Start a List workflow` for this list on the current item.

[image]

For more details check [How to trigger a SharePoint 2010 workflow from a SharePoint 2013 workflow](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sharepointdesigner/2012/08/17/how-to-trigger-a-sharepoint-2010-workflow-from-a-sharepoint-2013-workflow/)

Comment: Yes M.Qassas I have been doing the same as an alternative, triggering a 2010 workflow(for approval process) using a 2013 workflow. Well now it's pretty clear Workflow 2013 is different!